# FastAPI Python no value in the POST petition

Tags: python, post, parameters, fastapi

I have a function for FastAPI defined as:

```
@app.post("/rating")
def read_prediction(id: int, team: int, location: float, age: float):
```

The problem starts when I received a POST petition in which there is no value for one of the predefined parameters, as follows:

`*"POST /rating?id=27691&team=1673&location=328&age= HTTP/1.1" 422*`

With this request, it does not enter the function. I have tried different options, for example introduce a default value, but it does not work.

```
@app.post("/rating")
def read_prediction(id: int, team: int, location: float, age: float = 26.5):
```

Also with Optional

```
from typing import Optional
def read_prediction(id: int, team: int, location: float, age: Optional[float] = 26.5):
```

But I am not able to handle this exception. When the POST petition includes the age, the function works as expected.

Another solution that I have been thinking in, is to define multiple functions without the parameters that can be empty, but i don't know if it is the best way to solve it.

Comment: did you forget to use ***`@app.post(...)`***? Please add your ***"exact function"***

Comment: Use `?id=27691&team=1673&location=328` (without "partial `age` )

Answer (score 1):

Even though your intent is to post, it will work if you change post to get but it will not be meaningfull. Again since your intent is to post you should be using Models as given [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/#import-pydantics-basemodel) or add body for each parameter if you want it in request body or Query if you want it in query parameter or even both!

```
from fastapi import Path, Body, Query

@app.post("/rating")
def read_prediction(id: int = Query(...), age: float = Body(None)):
    """
    ... -> mandatory or None for optional
    """
```

adding default(26.5 or any other value) is not good in fn parameter itself, instead do it inside fn as required